# How to place paperclip images from development into production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, capistrano

I created a database of products on my local machine, which I now need to get onto a production server. The database of products is loaded in production. However, I can't seem to find a way to get my images to the production server.. Using **capistrano/nginx/AWS**

I need to somehow get the images from my local development server, which are stored in:

```
app_root/public/system
```

...into the production environment's system folder...

```
xxx.com/current/public/system
```

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Paperclip relies on the database to store the file info, so it's not easy to just copy and paste database records. You could use Rails' seeds to load the products, as long as the images for each product is accessible in the filesystem. For example:

```
# db/seeds.rb
products = Product.create([
    { name: "Shampoo",
      photo: File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'public', 'images', 'products', 'shampoo.png'))
    },
    { name: "Conditioner",
      photo: File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'public', 'images', 'products', 'conditioner.png'))
    },
  ])
```

Then run `rake db:seed` on the server.

Fwiw it's not strictly necessary to do this in the `seeds.rb` file - you could paste the above into a console window if you want.